# Different definitions for Secant varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have seen multiple definitions of the term secant variety for a variety $X$. For one I saw it defined as the Join of $X$ with itself. On the other hand I saw it as the Zariski closure of the unions of all linear spans of $2$ points in $X$.
These definitions are not the same are they? Or are they in some way projectively equivalent?

Comment: These are exactly the same.

Comment: @Mohan I see,  since the joint is defined in the Grassmannians I got confused and thought I couln't be the same

Comment: @Mohan Can I ask you something else about the definition? I saw the $k$-th secant variety can be defined as the closure of the linear spans of $k$ points in $X$. On the other hand I saw a definition where you only considered linearly independent points: Is this still the same definition?

Comment: When you take the closure the differences disappear.